# jquery eventstoppropagation no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo el siguiente código:

```
$('#paid_out').on('change', function(e){ 
    this.checked=!this.checked?!confirm('Esta acción va a anular la deuda documentada asociada a este egreso ¿Está seguro de eliminarla?'):true;
    
    if(this.checked) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation(); 
        return false;  
    }
});
```

Estoy intentando cancelar el flujo del evento al cancelar el confirm, pero no funciona. "paid_out" es un checkbox.

Comment: ¿Cuando lo quieres anular? ¿Al marcarlo o desmarcarlo?

Comment: cuando en el confirm se elija cancelar

Comment: Si pero cuando el checkbox está en blanco y cambia a seleccionado o siempre que cambie de estado quieres la confirmación?

Comment: cuando pase de seleccionado a deseleccionado

Comment: creo que el problema es que en otro lugar del codigo hay el mismo evento change

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera. Preguntas primero si el usuario intentó deseleccionarlo y le lanzas la confirmación. Si confirma, lo deseleccionas, si no, mantienes su estado.

```js
$('#paid_out').on('change', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).prop('checked')=== false){
      let confirmation = confirm('Esta acción va a anular la deuda documentada asociada a este egreso ¿Está seguro de eliminarla?');
      $(this).prop('checked', !confirmation);
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="paid_out" type="checkbox" checked>
```

Comment: en otra parte del código hay un change del mismo elemento, que termina el ciclo aún cuando en el otro se ha cancelado el confirm.  Veré que puedo hacer con eso.